# How do I save an image generated by imshow(image) into a variable?

Tags: image, matlab, save, imshow

This is my code. I want to save the image displayed on imshow(img) into a variable to use it later. Thanks!

```
img=imread('image1.bmp');
figure(1), imshow(img);

[r c]=ginput(4);
Bw=roipoly(img,r,c);
% figure,imshow(Bw)
   [R C]=size(Bw);

for i=1:R
    for j=1:C
        if Bw(i,j)==1
            img(i,j)=img(i,j);
        else
            img(i,j)=0;
        end
    end
end
figure,
imshow(img); title ('Output Image');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the classic `getframe / cdata` idiom.  With the figure window open, simply do this:

```
figure;
imshow(img); title('Output Image');
h = getframe;
im = h.cdata;
```

`h` is a handle to the current frame that is open, and the `cdata` field contains image data for the frame.  The above code stores the frame image data into a variable called `im` for use for later.

## Minor Comment

That `for` loop code to set the output is a bit inefficient.  You can do this completely vectorized and you'll notice significant speedups.

This code:

```
for i=1:R
    for j=1:C
        if Bw(i,j)==1
            img(i,j)=img(i,j);
        else
            img(i,j)=0;
        end
    end
end
```

... can be replaced with:

```
img(~BW) = 0;
```

I also don't understand why you'd need to store the image data inside the frame of `imshow`... when `img` already contains your data and you are ultimately showing the data contained in `img`.  Why can't you just use `img` directly for your application?  Nevertheless, the above solution will work.